# Creating multidimensional list of medicine dosage times

Tags: python, list

Let's suppose I am creating a program to manage medicines.
In a determinate function I am in need to create a list with two dimensions, the first one for medicines, and the second for their times in hours.

I got the following code:

```
for med in curr_result:
        print(med)
        hours_result = []
        hours_result.append([med[3]])
        for times in range(med[2]):
            if times != 0:
                hours_result[med_counter].append(
                    hours_result[med_counter][times - 1] + med[6])
        med_counter = med_counter + 1
    print(hours_result)
```

It outputs:

```
> ('Test1', '2014-03-16', 3, 7, 0, 0, 7)     
> ('Test2', '2014-03-20', 1, 20,40, 1, 0)    
> [[20]]
```

The correct result would be:

```
> [[7,14,21],[20]]
```

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: @SherMM The input is in the output. There is a "print(med)"  statement

Comment: SOMN, it's clearer and simpler if you just show the input (`curr_result`), instead of having your code `for med in curr_result: print(med)` the input into the output(!)

Comment: Also, please explain what the columns mean, it's very unclear. Seems like `med[2]` column is some sort of count; what is iterating `for times in range(med[2]): ...` and then `hours_result[med_counter][times - 1] + med[6]` supposed to represent? It's very unclear.

Comment: So somehow in the first line of output, the count from `med[2] = 3` is applied to the (base hour?) `med[6] = 7` to generate the range (of hours?) `[7,14,21]`. But you need to explain what these fields are doing. I don't think this question is a reusable resource for anyone else.

Comment: Anyway this could be done better with two one-line list comprehensions, and would be infinitely clearer. If only you would explain the mystery columns.

Comment: Aha! `med[3]` is the start hour, `med[2]` is the count, `med[6]` is the hour_step. Why didn't you just say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should init **hours_result** outside of the outer for loop, here it's set to `[]` for each med.

Answer (score 1):

Your data appears to have a schema: name, date, doses, start, ?, period, 
and you seem to want a list of dosage hours:

```
curr_result = [('Test1', '2014-03-16', 3, 7, 0, 0, 7),
               ('Test2', '2014-03-20', 1, 20,40, 1, 0)]

hours_result = []

for med in curr_result:
    hours = []
    for time in range(med[2]):
        hours.append(med[3] + time*med[6]) # 
    hours_result.append(hours)

print hours_result
```

prints:

```
[[7, 14, 21], [20]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but was already answered :)

Comment: @Claudiop Typically best to accept the answer that best answers your question.